# JSON to JSON conversion using Liquid templates as maps in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: liquid-template

this is my JSON source file format

```
{
    "BookingId":2,
    "BookingReferenceNumber":"A15",
    "BookingIndex":3
}
```

This is Liquid file for mapping

```
{            
   "Id":{{content.BookingId}},   
   "refNumber":"{{content.BookingReferenceNumber}}",
   "Index":{{content.BookingIndex}}       
}
```

JSON Output file should be like this

```
{            
   "Id":2,   
   "refNumber":"A15",
   "Index":3      
}
```

But I am getting JSON output without content

```
{            
   "Id":"",   
   "refNumber":"",
   "Index":""      
}
```

Please suggest proper liquid file format